# How is it possible to be able to browse the web, when I can't resolve domains?

Tags: linux, networking

My networking is clearly bollixed, but I can't figure out how:

```
derek@vinka:~$ nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

derek@vinka:~$ curl google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Surely, if I can't look up a domain, I shouldn't be able to browse to it. Can anybody explain what's going on  here?

`tracepath` is also just a long series of either `???` or `no reply` responses.

(fwiw, everything *was* working, but I'm trying to change my secondary router—on a 50' ethernet cable—connected to the cable modem/router to become an AP on  the same subnet, instead of being a router on its own subnet)

```
derek@vinka:~$ env | grep -i proxy
derek@vinka:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       vinka

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

derek@vinka:~$ 

derek@vinka:~$ nslookup
> server
Default server: 127.0.1.1
Address: 127.0.1.1#53
```

Interestingly, I get the same result from a system running NetworkManager and another running Connmand.

If I lookup through my router (`nslookup host 192.168.0.1`), I still can't get any resolutions, but browsers/curl/wget always work on my laptop, my raspberry Pi media server, and my phone—all of them running different OSes.

What about /etc/nsswitch?

```
derek@vinka:~$ grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal dns [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
```

Clearly that last `dns` is redundant, but it looks right, otherwise.

```
derek@vinka:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

On my media server:

```
derek@nas ~ $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by Connection Manager
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: It looks like the website or DNS mapping are cached somewhere on your network, can you ping a website by IP?

Comment: Does havahi deamon is instaleld on your distro ? Also no you basically cant browse the Web without dns on few site you could if you know the ip but most of thé time it wont work

Comment: Perchance google is in your hosts file? What does `server` command output after you launch `nslookup`?

Comment: Try disconnecting the secondary router, see if everything works after a while (might take a few seconds for the routes and DNS to update). Plug the secondary router back in and see if everything goes all haywire again. Then you know that it is the secondary router that is causing the problem.

Comment: You’re probably using a proxy, which is taking care of the DNS lookups for you. Check the output of `env | grep -i proxy`.

Comment: Nope. I'm absolutely not using a proxy

Comment: @trogdor I can not only _ping_ a website, I can browse to websites I've never seen before. It certainly appears that my browsers are doing DNS lookups, it's just `nslookup` and `dig` that aren't finding anything. One device might be totally bypassing any local DNS, but my phone's not that smart... oh! Unless Google has the bad habit of adding it's own DNS to the resolver on Android devices? Not something I've every heard of, but possible...

Comment: @ajeh No, google isn't in `/etc/hosts/`. That's exactly what you _should_ see when you browse to http://google.com/

Comment: @Auspex Please do run `server` command in `nslookup` and post the results.

Comment: @ajeh Ah! I'd misunderstood your suggestion. I thought it was a `server` command at the CLI, which I didn't have, rather than a subcommand of `nslookup` (which I've obviously never used, but equally obviously seems to be exactly what I need).

Comment: @Kiwy `avahi-daemon`? If that's what you meant, yes, it's running on both the machines I can actually investigate. I suspect it's running on my Android phone too. How would that affect `nslookup` _outside_ my local network? Yes, it should make  it easier to find devices  on my local subnet, but afaik it can't help you find `google.com`

Comment: What's 127.0.**1**.1 that you are using for a DNS server? Is there a DNS server living at that address?

Comment: @ajeh `systemd` strikes again. This time it's [`systemd-resolve`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolve.html).

Comment: @ajeh Yes, it's systemd, and yes, `127.0.0.1` is absolutely normal. But it wouldn't matter if I had systemd, anyway, at least on my laptop. Ubuntu has been using NetworkManager for years, and it always sets itself as the resolver, too. The question is not whether that's a good idea, but how my browsers are managing to look up domains through the _default_ resolver, when nslookup/dig need to be pointed upstream.

Comment: @ojs Removing the secondary AP from the network has no effect.

Comment: @Auspex It's not 127.0.0.1 - you are showing 127.0. **1** .1

Comment: @ajeh You do know that after the `127.` nothing else matters, right? 127.*.*.* is all the local network interface.

Comment: @Auspex they are variations on a theme. (NTP reference clocks are similar.)

Comment: @roaima Yes, /etc/resolv.conf shows `127.0.0.1` on one machine, and `127.0.1.1` on another (output above), just as they always have. Turns out that while both use `systemd` only the latter has `systemd-resolve`—but the behavior is the same on both.

Comment: @ajeh They're _not_ variations on a theme! The netmask on the `lo` interface is `255.0.0.0`—which makes  `127.0.0.1`, `127.0.1.1`, and `127.127.127.127` effectively the same address.

Comment: @Auspex "_effectively_", yes certainly. But "_technically_" they are different addresses for loopback. Some software uses this to differentiate between normal loopback and a private internal-only address.

Comment: In the end, I gave up using either AP as a DNS server. Turned `dnsmasq` on on my Raspberry Pi media server, turned off DHCP on the Virgin Media router, and the Pi sets the gateway for DHCP clients to the VM router. The problem has to be in the VM router, but beats me why. It's certainly nothing to do with `systemd`.

Comment: excellent question, could you strace the curl command?

Comment: Try adding 8.8.8.8 to /etc/resolv.conf like below nameserver 8.8.8.8 Share the output of: curl www.google.com and let us know..... cheers

Comment: @Raghaha That pretty much completely misses the point. If I add 8.8.8.8 as a nameserver, I'll presumably be able to resolve the domain lookups. My question is, why when my system's resolver **tells** me it can't resolve **any** domains, I'm still actually able to browse sites.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "browse the web", but firefox is using it's own resolver - https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/commitment-to-privacy/privacy-policy/firefox/

And pretty much any application can ignore your DNS settings and use it's own resolver. SO the fact that you don't have DNS setup correctly won't stop them.

Comment: Well, as you can see from the question, what I mean by "browse the web" included using `curl`. I'm pretty sure curl isn't smart enough to have its own resolver. In fact I used multiple browsers all with the same result, but curl is best for presenting the results here. Still, this is as close an answer as I've had!